# Sql query for visit counter not working as expected

Tags: sql, asp-classic

The followoing classic asp code is used to count the daily page visits on a website. It checks the date of last record then:

- inserts a new row if date was changed
- Updates the previous record if date was not changed

However there are multiple unwanted records everyday with duplicate dates with 1 or 2 or 3 visits and also a real record with say 10000 visits on same date. What are possible reasons for duplicate records?

```
recordset.open "select top 1 id from visit order by id desc",objcon
    if recordset("mdate")=today then
    
        sql="update visit set counter=counter+1 where id=" & recordset("id")
        objcon.execute sql
        
        else
        
        sql="insert into visit (mdate,counter) values ('" & today & "','1')"
        objcon.execute sql
    
    end if
recordset.close
```

Comment: I'm rather confused.  How is `mdate` defined?

Comment: For how long you've been coming to this site asking questions, you don't seem to learn or adhere to previous advice, SQL Injection, concurrency issues these are issues you should by now know how to avoid. It's painful seeing the same user making the same mistakes over and over.

Comment: Thank you @user692942  I know how to avoid injection. You have some important mindsets and expect that to be important for eveyone. This is a raw sample code and will be edited and improved many times before an important usage. Why should I be afraid of a sample code from the security perception? Are you afraid of copying these codes by other amature ones?

Comment: @AliSheikhpour don't get the concept of writing it wrong for a sample. If you are going to write sample code that requires the use of parameterised queries include them. How exactly would you write this code if it wasn't a sample and why do you even need help with sample code? None of it makes any sense.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a race condition.  There are two visits at the same time for the same id.  Both of them run a query and see that the `id` is not in the table.  Voila!  Both of them decide to insert a new row.  And you get duplicates.

There are several approaches to fixing this.  One is to lock the table for the duration of the process.  I think I prefer the following:

- Define a unique index on `(id, date)`, so the *database* ensures uniqueness.
- Attempt to `insert` a new row with a count of 1.
- If the `insert` fails, then update the count by 1.